# Order php echo output

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I have a Joomla site where is installed a custom component. In that component I print the Joomla usernames into a html table. And there is a checkbox, where I can choose the users by name.

```
<option value="<?php echo $allUser->id; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> ><?php echo $allUser->name; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

That is working ok, but I want to order the usernames. Ex. I have 3 registered user:

```
1-Joe
2-Katie
3-Bill
```

And I want to specify the order in which I display, such as:

```
1-Bill
2-Joe
3-Katie
```

By default there are ordered by registration ID (I think). What is the right way doing this? And how to do this?

```
public function getUsersById($id = NULL, $select = NULL)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($select);
    $query->from('#__users AS u');
    $query->join('LEFT',' #__user_usergroup_map AS ugm ON u.id=ugm.user_id');
    $query->where('ugm.group_id!="8"');
    $query->where('u.id="'.$id.'"');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $row;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: can you provide your mysql select code?

Comment: Don't forget to [properly escape your values here](https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries).

Comment: what do you mean ? insert escape to these queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your results using the [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in MySQL:

```
$query->join('LEFT'," #__user_usergroup_map AS ugm ON u.id=ugm.user_id
                     order by FIELD(u.name, 'Bill', 'Joe', 'Katie')");
```

Make the above change to your code to achieve a custom order as specified in your question.

If you have a more complex order specification, you may also take advantage of the [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) such as in:

```
ORDER BY (
           CASE name
           WHEN 'Bill' THEN 0
           WHEN 'Joe' THEN 1
           WHEN 'Katie' THEN 2
           END
         )
```

Comment: I dont want to order by username, I want a mixed order (specified order by me)

Comment: If I want to order by a column like the registrationDate ?

Comment: I have to order by registration date the users because that the column what I can easy modify:

  $query->order('registerDate ASC');

Comment: I edited the answer to include another approach for more complex sort customization if you need that.

Comment: I will use this sorting customization is the next, it is really helpful, for now to fix this sorting problem I have to sort by a column (like registerDate), but dont wanna work

Answer (score 1):

See below. You will want to add the `$query->order` line with your appropriate information for ordering.

```
 public function getUsersById($id = NULL, $select = NULL)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($select);
        $query->from('#__users AS u');
        $query->join('LEFT',' #__user_usergroup_map AS ugm ON u.id=ugm.user_id');
        $query->where('ugm.group_id!="8"');
        $query->where('u.id="'.$id.'"');
        $query->order('**column you want to order by** **ASC/DESC**');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $row = $db->loadObjectList();
        return $row;
    }
```